# Is it OK not to call close method?

Tags: java-io

Below code is the serialize method of org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils(spring-core.3.2.1.jar).
As you can see, there is no oos.close method. Is it OK not to call close method?

[image: org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils]

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` does have a `close()` method (in the implementation of `ICloseable` in its `OutputStream` base class).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You mean Closeable, and it isn't inherited from OutputStream, it is in ObjectOutputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, it's okay - the two streams involved (the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`) don't use any unmanaged resources (file handles, network handles) etc so it's okay for the garbage collector to just take care of it.

Personally I usually close even streams like that, just to be in the right habits and in case someone changes the type of the stream to one that *does* have unmanaged resources, but I don't think it really counts as a *bug* in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`close` should be called by most sane objects when they are destroyed (garbage collected).  But since you don't know exactly when that will happen, you should make it a point to call `close` yourself, so that the cleanup (file buffers flushed, network kissoff performed) happens when you expect it to.